# Mysql Query find article follower / last with no follower

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to make a small shop based on a provided article list - generally no problem.
BUT there are articles in this list, which have newer versions with new article numbers. for example:

```
Article Nr. | Title  | Price | New Article  
1001        | Test 1 | 10.0  | 1003  
1002        | Test 2 | 20.0  |   
1003        | Test 3 | 13.0  |  ( = new Version of Test 1)
```

User should be able to search in all article numbers to get the title & price. If he types the "old" number 1001 he should get the title & price of the new version: 1003. (But this is only an easy example, its not limited how many articles are between the searched articlenr and the final articlenr)

Before I script a complex solution in php, I would like to ask if there is an "easier" way to get the correct article with a special database select?

--

Just thinking if the following (summarized) php code could be much easier than the requested mysql query:

```
function searcharticle(search_nr){ 
 SELECT nr, title, price, newnr FROM articles WHERE nr = '$search_nr';
 if(empty($newnr)){ $title = ... }else{ searcharticle($newnr); }
}
```

what do you think?

Comment: If there are many articles between searched and final what output do you expect?

Comment: in the actual export-file is a chain of up to 4 articles (eg. 1001 > 1003 > 1011 > 1028 but maybe in the near future again a new version is added ...) in there system is no limit for such following articles

Comment: But are you expecting a whole list of newer articles or just the last one?

Comment: In which case there isn't an easy way to do this in MySQL. I would normally suggest using a recursive CTE to find the final article, but MySQL doesn't have them - I think writing a UDF to loop through results is your only option as the data stands. Alternatively, consider updating your New Article field so that it always points to the newest article.

Comment: @MarkBannister thanks for your comment. unfortunately i don't have the possibility to influence the provided list. so i think it's the best way to loop through the results with php maybe with the help of a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

Managing hierarchical data in mysql is not an easy task, but it is possible.

Assuming `articles` table has `article_num, Title, Price, new_article` columns, all of them of VARCHAR type, with new_article as empty string for newest versions, this should do the trick of finding the Title and Price of newest version of given article:

```
SELECT a.Title, a.Price FROM articles a
JOIN
( SELECT 
  @article_num as prev_version,
  @article_num := 
     ( SELECT new_article
          FROM articles
       WHERE article_num = prev_version ) AS article_num
  FROM
    ( SELECT @article_num := '1001' ) AS starting_num,
    articles
    WHERE @article_num <> '' ) newer_articles
ON newer_articles.prev_version = a.article_num 
   AND newer_articles.article_num = ''
```

Regarding your php solution - yes, recursive approach in a language that allows it is a lot easier to code for adjacency list, also easier to read and maintain and performance should not be a problem as there won't be that many new versions of any article.

Comment: Thanks piotrm for your code example - it looks very good ;) but i think it's too far away from my knowlegde to unerstand it ... - I will give it a try and hope it works

Answer (score 0):

This should help at least by getting up to 4 levels deep on hierarchy of renewed items...

```
select
      Articles.*
   from
      ( select
            IF( a4.ArticleNr is not null, a4.ArticleNr,
               IF( a3.ArticleNr is not null, a3.ArticleNr,
                  IF( a2.ArticleNr is not null, a2.ArticleNr, A1.ArticleNr ))) as FinalArticle
           from
              Articles a1
                 left join Articles a2
                    on a1.NewArticle = a2.ArticleNr
                    left join Articles a3
                       on a2.NewArticle = a3.ArticleNr
                       left join Articles a4
                          on a3.NewArticle = a4.ArticleNr
           where
              a1.ArticleNr = '1001' ) QualifiedArticle

      JOIN Articles
         ON QualifiedArticle.FinalArticle = Articles.ArticleNr
```

The nested IF( IF( IF( ))) will start with the 4th generation deep "newest" version article... if found, it gets that, otherwise, gets 3rd newest, to 2nd newest to the single article the user actually provided.  Since this is a self-join, it will only return a single record and be quite fast.  From that, it joins the one final record with the articles table on THAT MATCHED find to get whatever the "newest" entry would be.

Comment: it's a good idea but it's a limited solution - as I mentioned before, there are already articles that have a history of 4 versions. if these articles get a new version this solution will not work ...